# How to give div with dynamic content a stretchable background or border on hover

Tags: css, html

This is proving a challenge. We have a:

```
<div id="inhalt_rechts" style="width:31.47925%; float:right; border-left:1px dotted #969696; margin:2.3475% 0%; padding:0% 1.17375%;">
```

The div is fed with dynamic content (mostly but not always img followed by text) which stretches vertically.

We need to:

1.make the complete div clickable so we can give it a hover effect;

2.give the hover effect this (background/border?) image which stretches vertically with the content:
[image: should this be a background or a border?]

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why does it matter what its content is?

Comment: Thought about using the img tag as a workaround, but it's not always there so not really relevant.

Comment: This is basic stuff and any search related to the question pulls up multiple solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would do is use

http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_borders.asp

to create the shadows with the `box-shadow` property

Then I would make another div on the bottom that has the little arrow.

http://jsfiddle.net/6Nncm/

Comment: Works a treat. Thanks for the easy 'non-offensive' answer!

Answer (score 0):

try this duh

```
html
<a href="">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consecteur </a>

css
a {
    border:1px solid #eee;
    border-radius::10px;
    box-shadow:1px solid #eee;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
}
a:after {
    background:url( arrow-image.png ) no-repeat;
    bottom:0;
    content:"";
    height:20px;
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    margin-left:-50px; // the width of the arrow / 2
    width:100px;
}
a:hover {
    background:pink;
}
```

Obviously you need to replace background, border colors and stuff